# Javascript comma useaged

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Hello everyone I'm trying to print `"Invalid password, Must Contain:"`, but my problem is when I wrote the code in JavaScript, the comma seems to be a operator not a plain English comma. Its printing "Invalid password Must Contain:" instead "Invalid password, Must Contain:" How would I just want the real English comma `,` not the operator?

```
", <b>Invalid password, Must Contain:</b> "
```

**Update:** I changed into table so the format will look better. the comma is inside the `if` statement

```
if (sError.length==0) {
    if (!validatePassword(sNewPass)) {
        sError += ",<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'style='color:red;font-size:small;margin-right:30px;'><tr><td><b>Invalid password, Must Contain:</b></tr><tr></td><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>Between eight (8) to twelve (12) characters </li></tr><tr></td><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one upper-case letter (A-Z) </li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one lower-case letter (a-z)</li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one number (0-9)</li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one special character</li></td></tr></table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's inside a string literal (e.g. `"foo,bar"` or `'foo,bar'`) then no, a comma is just a regular character. You'll have to show us some code that produces the described behavior. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: Please only use snippets for complete, executable examples. If all you have is just a few lines of code that cannot be run by themselves, just use code blocks.

Answer (score -1):

working fiddle:

```
var sError="Error Occured"; 
sError += ",<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'style='color:red;font-size:small;margin-right:30px;'><tr><td><b>Invalid password, Must Contain:</b></tr><tr></td><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>Between eight (8) to twelve (12) characters </li></tr><tr></td><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one upper-case letter (A-Z) </li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one lower-case letter (a-z)</li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one number (0-9)</li></td></tr><tr><td><li style='margin-left:40px;'>At least one special character</li></td></tr></table>";

$("#error").html(sError);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/619st2oq/

Comment: This appears to be a copy of the code in the question. What was the problem?

Comment: I ran his code on a fresh fiddle and it is working fine.... I want to know what different he is doing.